# Scooter doesn't start with the help of choke

Tags: tvs-jupiter

I have a problem with my TVS Jupiter Million R.

When i pull the choke and kick start ...the scooter doesn't start and when I pull down the choke the scooter start very easily in one or two kick. But it goes off automatically due to cold engine.

So now i start every morning without pulling choke and giving a revs for 10/15 second and then I pull the choke but the rear wheel doesn't round though the sound get change after pulling the choke. Before it use to work and now my mood really turn off due to that.

Request you to please help.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! There may be a language barrier going on here, as it seems something is lost in translation. Could you edit your question with a bit more information so we can understand better what's going on? How many miles (kms) are on the bike? What is the engine size? What year was the bike made? Have you done any maintenance on the bike to remedy the situation? Help us a little here and we can probably help you.

Answer (score 0):

Pulling choke causing engine to shutdown.

This happens because of slack in choke cable or wire which activate choke mechanism in carburetor.

To resolve this issue you need to adjust slack in choke wire. This can be done easily by opening front cover where indicators are mounted. Behind this front cover, choke cable is present and easily adjusted to requirement so that there should not be any slack in wire.

Answer (score 0):

A richer air/fuel mix ( more gasoline) is needed to start and for a short time ( seconds to minutes, depending on the engine, temperature ,etc). The choke restricts air flow in the carb which causes it to suck more gasoline making a richer mix. In a typical case one may use full choke for one kick, that puts rich mix in the manifold. Then set the choke to 1/2, this will give a slightly rich mix for cold running and kick to start. After a minute, turn the choke off because rich mix is no longer needed. There is an unlimited variety of variations to this basic sequence for various engines.